# How do I single out a variable in a column in R

Tags: r, dataset

I'm using this LA area crime dataset in R. http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/crimes-2012-2015/resource/a2369c45-fcdb-4819-b3fc-979c7b737aed
I'm trying to separate the crime "Burglary" from the rest of the crimes in the column named CrmCd.Desc. Here is my code so far:

```
crime_data <- read.csv('/Users/my_user_name/Downloads/Crimes_2012-2015.csv')
View(crime_data)
crime_data$CrmCd.Desc
```

I tried this:

```
burg <- crime_data$CrmCd.Desc['Burglary']
```

And it showed me this which is not what I'm looking for.

```
[1] <NA>
158 Levels:  ABORTION/ILLEGAL ARSON ... WEAPONS POSSESSION/BOMBING
```

This shows the entire column of CrmCd.Desc. How do I just show the rows that contain "Burglary" within this column? Thanks

Comment: Just updated what I tried

Comment: [This is the first dupe I found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27709404/903061), seems to match pretty well. [This is an R-FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7106330/903061), but seems like a less good match.

Comment: use `crime_data <- read.csv('/Users/my_user_name/Downloads/Crimes_2012-2015.csv', as.is=TRUE)` This way, you won't have to deal with factor variables and can work with character variables, which are much nicer.

Comment: You will need to do a little research on subsetting.  See `?subset`.  This will give you a start:  `burg <- crime_data[ crime_data$CrmCd.Desc == 'Burglary', ]`.